# How are the TI operating systems coded not to have floating point error?

Tags: floating-point, floating-point-precision, ti-basic

I ran a test on my graphing calculator to check for floating point error, and after forty eight hours of complete and utter randomness, the calculator had not lost a single digit of precision.

How does TI pull this off?

Comment: Can you give an example of "complete and utter randomness"?  What are you comparing against?

Comment: It's not a literal statement. Sorry if everything on here is meant to be taken exactly literally; I didn't intend to impair the point of the question with a little bit of silliness, nor did it.

Comment: I'm asking for an example of what you were trying; at the moment your question has zero information content.  How can we possibly answer without knowing the context?

Comment: I quote: "I ran a test on my graphing calculator to check for floating point error, and after forty-eight hours..." Isn't that enough? That tells you that: 1) I ran a test for floating point error. 2) It lasted for 48 hours. Now, let's look at the question: "How are the TI operating systems coded not to have floating point error?" Isn't it answerable now?

Comment: No, because you haven't told us anything about that test, i.e. what operations it consisted of, nor how you were verifying the results.

Comment: Yeah, it is. Because you don't need to check my work. My question, I repeat: "How are the TI operating systems coded not to have floating point error?" I really don't even NEED body text. The question is self-explanatory! Anyone could answer it without any more details, so long as they know the answer.

Comment: I give up.  You asked a shoddy question, and you got my downvote.  Let's leave it at that.

Comment: I don't understand why not adding irrelevant details made it shoddy, but okay. You're entitled to an opinion, I suppose.

Comment: I know it's 11 years later, but I would also be interested in your original testing method, as I have actually encountered floating point errors in some instances that I'm trying to track down the cause of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TI-89 and TI-92 avoid error by using [symbolic computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_computation) to store values *exactly*.

Actual floating-point computations ("approx" mode on the 89/92) *do* have errors.  They're just harder to notice because the TI calculators display fewer digits than they store.  Also, they use decimal instead of binary.

For example, if you enter the expression `1/3*3-1` on a TI-89 in "approx" mode, you get the answer `⁻1.ᴇ⁻14` instead of the `0` you get in exact mode.  Internally, the calculation is done as follows:

- `1/3` gives `0.33333333333333`, rounded to 14 significant digits.
- Multiplying by 3 gives `0.99999999999999`.  Because of rounding, this displays as `1.`
- Subtracting 1 gives `-0.00000000000001`, or -1e-14.

Answer (score 0):

There *is* actually some precision error on the popular TI-84+ calculator, although it is less prominent than on other platforms.

For example: in JavaScript and a number of other prominent programming languages that use IEEE-754 binary floating points, `0.1+0.2` will result in `0.30000000000000004`. This particular example is not a prominent problem on Texas TI calculators because they use a base-10 format, not base-2.

There are, however, still precision issues on the TI-84+, such as this example from the [TI Basic Wiki](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/fpart):

> #### Watch Out For Precision Issues
>
> ```
> 1/3*3→X   // X is expected to be 1
> X         // Displays 1, but is actually 0.99999999999999 in memory
> iPart(X)  // Displays 0
> fPart(X)  // Displays 1, but is actually 0.99999999999999 in memory
> ```
>
> Somewhat unintuitively, the code above displays the results 1, 0 and 1. This is due to the calculator storing values to 14 digits of precision, but rounding the value to 10 digits to fit on the home screen. Because of this, `fPart()` can appear to return values of 1 or -1.
>
> *Tip:* If you enter a value in the list editor screen, you will be able to see all 14 digits of precision. This can help you troubleshoot issues like these.
>
> One workaround is to round the numbers prior to calling `iPart()` or `fPart()`, if you don't mind the slight loss in precision from 14 significant digits to 9 decimal places:
>
> ```
> 1/3*3→X
> iPart(round(X,9))   // Displays the expected result 1
> fPart(round(X,9))   // Displays the expected result 0
> ```
>
> (The parameter 9 is not technically required here since 9 is the default, but is shown for clarity and in case you want to customize the level of precision.)